# Push a docker image with Curl (Or Jfrog CLI)

Tags: docker, curl, artifactory, docker-registry, jfrog-cli

**TLDR: I try to push a docker image with curl, but the uploaded image is broken.**

**Context:** Due to connectivity limitation, I have to access our Artifactory docker registry through an API gateway. Docker commands as login can't work as it tries to connect to a subdomain (eg my-registry.public-domain.com).

I can push/pull files to/from artifactory using Artifactory API with curl/jfrog CLI. My goal is to push a valid docker image to this Artifactory using the API only.

What I did is:

##### Build the docker

```
docker build . --file Dockerfile -t helloworld:v1.1
```

##### Save the image to a local file

```
docker image save --output=helloworld-v1.1.tar helloworld:v1.1
```

##### Untar the .tar image

```
mkdir v1.1; tar -xvf helloworld-v1.1.tar -C v1.1
```

##### Upload each layer and the manifest.json to artifactory

```
jfrog rt upload "v1.1/*" my-registry/helloworld/ --url xyz.com/artifactory --user foo --password bar
```

(Previous command behave like a recursive curl put in the v1.1/ folder)

##### Result:

[image]

Each layer and the manifest .json have been uploaded on Artifactory but something is wrong. Docker info are empty:

```
Unable to extract Docker metadata for
'my-registry/helloworld/v1.1/'
```

And trying to pull the image from Openshift result in this error (It works with images uploaded the usual way on the same Artifactory):

```
Failed to pull image "my-registry.my-artifactory/helloworld:v1.1": rpc
error: code = Unknown desc = pinging container registry
l-docker-dev-workspace-dev.a-artifactory.vt.ch: invalid status code
from registry 400 (Bad Request)
```

**Do you have any clue to explain such a behaviour? How can I transfer my .tar docker image to Artifactory to then be usable like any other image?**

Any help is welcome,
Have a great day!

Comment: Not sure about a solution, but can you also share why you want to do this? As you are already using `docker` to build. Why not `push` with it?

Comment: See how to use the JFrog CLI for this (+ some bonus actions): https://jfrog.com/blog/manage-your-docker-builds-with-jfrog-cli-in-5-easy-steps/

Comment: Hi @EldadAssis, unfortunately the docker push command doesn't work because of network issues, as explained previously my Artifactory is accessible behind an API gateway only. Docker login/push would just fail.
Thank you for your link but unfortunately it does not provide information about sending a docker image with the API :/

Comment: I don't have a solution here, but I would insist solving the API gateway restriction with whoever owns it. Imagine buying a brand new car, but you are restricted from using its media system. You buy the car, you expect to use the media system...

Comment: What will you do with the image after you push it? You won't be able to pull it with docker either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone looking to do the same thing, **this thread answered my questions**: [Docker Private Registry Image Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59841918/docker-private-registry-image-upload)

I had to modify the script, as some of the commands were failing, and also to enable the upload of a docker image with multiple layers, but this is it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload a .tar file to a Docker-Type repository.

If you want to "distort" the use of Docker, you should try to use a repository of Type Generic.

However, I do not suggest this solution; I would try to understand if possible to review the network configurations to be able to use Artifactory normally.